# Configure truststore for servicemix

Tags: truststore, apache-servicemix

I have osgi bundle which route message from webservice to remote ejb (on glassfish) by use of camel routing. In order to access remote jndi I need to set up truststore. How can I do that? Is it any configuration in camel route or I have to do it by system properties?

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your route, Have you tried the [camel JSSE Utility](http://camel.apache.org/camel-configuration-utilities.html)?

Answer (score 0):

you could try putting the following properties in the system.properties file within the etc folder:

```
javax.net.ssl.keyStore=<keystore location>
javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=<keystore password>
javax.net.ssl.trustStore=<truststore location>
javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=<truststore password>
```